# Calendar.setTimeInMillis giving Different value after setting the time

Tags: calendar

I am working with getting previous date for various time zone based on the current date.Right now in my code, I got the US current time in milli seconds and then setting the time which in another Calendar object.
Then I am modifying that Calendar object Date with negative values to get previous dates.
When I checked, Calendar object is returning different values than the values which I set.May be I did not understand how Calendar object works.
Please explain why the time is different.

Below code gets the current time in US

```
Timestamp currTimeInGMT = DateTimeUtils.getCurrentTimeInGMT();
Timestamp currTime = DateTimeUtils.convertDateTime(currTimeInGMT,TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
```

Using the above code, I am getting Current US time as `September 18 1.12 AM` Then I am converting the time into milli seconds using this code

```
Long currentTimeInLong = currTime.getTime();
```

Then I am setting the above time in Calendar object

```
Calendar yesterdayCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
yesterdayCal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
```

After setting the time,

First I tried to get time from Calendar object using `yesterdayCal.getTime()`, I am getting `September 18 1.12 AM`

Then I tried to get Date, Hour, Minute using below code

```
Date=yesterdayCal.get(Calendar.DATE)
Hour=yesterdayCal.get(Calendar.HOUR)
Minute=yesterdayCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

I am getting the following results.

```
Date=17, Hour=12, Minute=42
```

Why I am getting two different results for two methods `getTime() and get()`.

As @mwe answered, if it sets the time in UTC, then I should get the same time for both the methods even if its wrong time.

Please explain clearly, as I am really confused with these methods

Answer (score 0):

If you use setTimeInMillis it sets the time in UTC.
So you have to add the time difference to you time zone, PST, to the long value.

yesterdayCal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis+8000l);